# Historical big data slow queries

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, bigdata, query-optimization

I have problem with slow queries.

> **PS**

**MariaDB**: mariadb:10.3.25 - **InnoDB**

I optimized most  DB configurations

> **Structure**

```
create table customers
(
    id              bigint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
 
    email           varchar(255)                                                                                 null,
    full_name       varchar(255)                                                                                 null,
    country         varchar(2)                                                                                   null,
    first_name      varchar(255)                                                                                 null,
    second_name     varchar(255)                                                                                 null,
    company_name    varchar(255)                                                                                 null,
    gender          char                                                                                         null,
    birth_date      date                                                                                         null,
    state           varchar(3)                                                                                   null,
null,
    custom_field_1  varchar(255)                                                                                 null,
    custom_field_2  varchar(255)                                                                                 null,
    custom_field_3  varchar(255)                                                                                 null,
    created_at      timestamp                                                                                    null,
    updated_at      timestamp                                                                                    null,
    deleted_at      timestamp                                                                                    null
)
    collate = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

```
create table customer_daily_stats
(
    date        date                   not null,
    campaign_id  bigint                 not null,
    customer_id bigint                 not null,
    event_1        int unsigned default 0 not null,
    event_2       int unsigned default 0 not null,
    event_3      int unsigned default 0 not null,
    event_4        int unsigned default 0 not null,
    event_5   int unsigned default 0 not null,
    constraint customer_daily_stats_date_customer_id_campaign_id_unique
        unique (date, customer_id, campaign_id)
)
    collate = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

create index customer_daily_stats_customer_id_date_index
    on customer_daily_stats (customer_id, date);

create index customer_daily_stats_campaign_id_index
    on customer_daily_stats (campaign_id);
```

**customers** ~ 1 - 5 millions rows

**customer_daily_stats** ~ 1 - 100 millions rows

> **Queries**

```
select 
    customers.*,
    IFNULL(
            SUM(events_aggregation.event_1),
            0
        ) as event_1,
    IFNULL(
            SUM(events_aggregation.event_2),
            0
        ) as event_2,
    IFNULL(
            SUM(events_aggregation.event_3),
            0
        ) as event_3,
    IFNULL(
            SUM(events_aggregation.event_4),
            0
        ) as event_4
from
    `customers`
        left join customer_daily_stats as events_aggregation on `customers`.`id` = `events_aggregation`.`customer_id`
        and `events_aggregation`.`date` between '2021-09-06' and '2022-07-06'
group by
    `customers`.`id`;
```

> **Problems**

Main idea is to have possibility to get aggregation by any dates.

Problem is that works too slow now and i need to do addition aggregations which decrease  performance. One more problem i don't have a lot of disc space (250G and about 80% used already).

I have:

- **customers** ~ 1.5m
- **customer_daily_stats** ~ 50.000
- **query speed** ~ 5s

> **Questions**

- Is there any methods to optimize my DB or another tools?
- Is there any DBs that help my to increase performance?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your **index definitions**, and the **output of EXPLAIN**. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the indexes.  You currently have

```
unique (date, customer_id, campaign_id)
INDEX(customer_id, date)
INDEX(campaign_id)
```

Maybe Change to:

```
PRIMARY KEY(customer_id, date, campaign_id)
INDEX(campaign_id)
```

BUT...  And this is a big BUT.  This rearrangement of indexing *may* significantly hurt other queries.  We really need to see

- All the big queries
- `EXPLAIN SELECT` for each

Did you notice that the range is 10 months *plus 1 day*?  This is because `BETWEEN` is 'inclusive'.

If 80% of disk is already used, you are in deep weeds.  Any fixes will require more than 20% of the disk to achieve.

One thing to do (when you have enough disk space) is to shrink `BIGINT` (8 bytes, probably an excessive range) and `INT UNSIGNED` (4 bytes, 4 billion max) to smaller int types where practical.

I'm confused.  These seem to contradict each other; please clarify:

> customer_daily_stats ~ 1 - 100 millions rows
> customer_daily_stats ~ 50.000

Some more things to help with the analysis:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size
RAM size
disk footprint for tables (GB)
```

Comment: You are right. Problem in composite key `PRIMARY KEY(customer_id, date, campaign_id)`
Actually started checking question style as @O. Jones recommend and found this problem. Now trying to implement it to staging but in local environment have good results. Thank you!